# Highcharts issue when dealing with 3D pie and large labels

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am using highcharts 3D pie and if some label is a little bit long it does not resize correctly.

Here it is an example which I have taken from `highcharts` documentation and forked it for getting large labels.

http://jsfiddle.net/78wr256o/

It is important to mention that I would prefer to display the whole name and not cropping it. Resizing correctly the chart, keeping it centered and moving labels position if it is possible.

This is the initial version:
[image]

This is exactly the same chart but with a large label:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html and css to format data labels.

```
series: [{...
    dataLabels: {
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
           "width": "30px"
        }
    ......
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/8d517w3v/

It doesn't crop rather wrap labels around and make graph centered.

Comment: The problem there is that the label overlaps other labels

Comment: It wouldn't be easy to have long labels auto adjust themselves based on space available in plot area. This can be an issue with every type of chart. The best is to predict using little bit of information about label length and position to determine what styling can help to make them appear clean. Or use legend to show graph and labels separately.

Comment: I used part of your solution and then I had to crop the text. I believe that there isn't actually a way of doing what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Since it is an html, you have an option of having long text scroll-able horizontally instead of cropping it.